# list of upcoming birthday oracle plsql

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have a problem on my hand. I am working on an application where user wants to send the wish cards to his clients whose birthday is within user provided FROM and TO date , irrespective of the year. I.e. the search results should be on the basis of the Month and date only. e.g my input parameteres are from date: "12/05" (December 05)and To Date: "01/04" (January 04). Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this query condition. It selects `birthdate` if it is in one month interval from now. Birthdate can be from any year:

```
where
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(birthdate,'dd.mm')||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') ,
between
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'dd.mm')||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') 
and ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'dd.mm')||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY'),1)
```

If user inputs date range as for example '02/03' and '23/06' ('P1' and 'P2' in this query)   then use following condition.

```
where
(
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(birthdate,'dd.mm')||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') ,
between
TO_DATE('P1'||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') 
and
TO_DATE('P2'||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') 
)

OR
(
    (TO_DATE('P1'||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') 
        > TO_DATE('P2'||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') )
    and 

    (
     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(birthdate,'dd.mm')||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') ,
     between
     TO_DATE('P1'||'.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') 
     and
     TO_DATE('31.12.1900','DD.MM.YYYY') 
     OR
     TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(birthdate,'dd.mm')||'.1901','DD.MM.YYYY') ,
     between
     TO_DATE('01.01.1901','DD.MM.YYYY') 
     and
     TO_DATE('P2'||'.1901','DD.MM.YYYY') 


    )

)
```

Comment: Valex thanks for your time. Actually problem is that its a user input date range. and user can input any criteria for two dates in "MM/DD"  format

Comment: Thanks for the updated query and after using this query my problem is almost resolved except one scenario. Now problem is that if user inputs TO date less than FROM date than application is returning the incorect result. e.g if user enters criteria FROM date: 12/04 and TO date: 01/03 (i.e. he wants to see the results from December 4 to January 03) in this case the query is not returning the correct result

Comment: Important to note that the above code will not work for leap dates. 1990 was not a leap year. Need to use 1904 or some other leap year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extract function of PLSQL:

```
extract(MONTH FROM DATE '2003-08-22') would return 8
extract(DAY FROM DATE '2003-08-22') would return 22
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php

Answer (score 0):

assuming you've stored DOB as a DATE lets say column = "DOB" in table PPL.

ie for the raw set:

```
FIRSTNAME                        LASTNAME                         DOB
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- ---------
Joe                              Bloggs                           03-JAN-90
Jane                             Doe                              05-JAN-40
Adam                             West                             05-DEC-76
```

we get

```
SQL> select firstname, lastname,  dob, next_bday
 2    from (select firstname, lastname, dob,
 3                  case when to_date(to_char(dob, 'mmdd'), 'mmdd') < trunc(sysdate)
 4                    then add_months(to_date(to_char(dob, 'mmdd'), 'mmdd'), 12)
 5                    else to_date(to_char(dob, 'mmdd'), 'mmdd')
 6                  end next_bday
 7            from ppl)
 8   where next_bday < add_months(trunc(sysdate), 1);

FIRS LASTNA DOB       NEXT_BDAY
---- ------ --------- ---------
Joe  Bloggs 03-JAN-90 03-JAN-13
Adam West   05-DEC-76 05-DEC-12
```